# Sorting array kills javascript instance on element (i.e. wysiwyg-editor)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a CMS-like feature that has an article with multiple particles (called blocks). A particle can be a either a rich text field or a table. Based on the Block's `discr` attribute, a Quill or Handsontable instance should be initiated.

This works perfectly, until I reorder the blocks. When I've got a Quill instance and a Handsontable instance, after reordering them, the Quill gets a context menu from the Handsontable and the Quill instance gets a toolbar.

I'm new to Vue.js, but I already understand that happens. I've read [List Rendering Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) and [Why isn’t the DOM updating?](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/). The two `div.chapterblock` elements don't get reordered (like a jQuery-like application probably would do), but only their content changes. When I use the inspector, I see the `.chapterblock#id` and it's content changing, not moving. The (Quill/Handsontable/whatever) instance is bound to a specific DOM element and stays bound to the element, even if it changes.

But what I don't (yet) understand is how to solve the problem. How can I reorder items and keep the Quill/Handsontable instance on the right elements? Destroying and re-initializing the instances doesn't feel right.

My template:

```
<div class="chapterblock" v-for="(block, index) in blocks" v-bind:data-id="block.id">
    <template v-if="block.discr == 'html'">
        <div class="quill" v-html="block.content"></div>
    </template>

    <template v-if="block.discr == 'table'">
        <script type="application/json" v-html="block.content"></script>
        <div v-bind:id="'handsontable_' + block.id" class="handsontable-wrapper"></div>
    </template>

    <button v-if="index !== 0" v-on:click="move(block, 'up')">up</button>
    <button v-if="index !== 1" v-on:click="move(block, 'down')">down</button>
</div>
```

Vue instance:

```
return new Vue({
  //...
  computed: {
    blocks: function () {
      return this.chapter.blocks.sort(function compare (a, b) {
        if (a.position < b.position) {
          return -1
        }
        if (a.position > b.position) {
          return 1
        }
        return 0
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    move: function (block, direction) {
      if (direction === 'up') {
        block.position = block.position - 1
      } else if (direction === 'down') {
        block.position = block.position + 1
      }
      // fetch to save position
    }
}
```

Comment: could you use flexbox ordering to achieve what you want :)

Comment: You're right, that would be a nice work-around. But still: I want to understand Vue.js ;).

Comment: That's fair sorry angular guy here xD hope you find a solution if i have some time i'll try have a go when i'm less busy at work xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `key` attribute on the v-for loop to reorder the elements, instead of replacing their contents:

From https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key:

> To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key attribute for each item. An ideal value for key would be the unique id of each item.